# Open a new browser window in GWT containing a Widget/Panel

Tags: java, gwt

I know you can open a new browser window using the Window.open() function directing it to a specific URL. However, is it possible to open a new browser Window containing a GWT Panel? And if it is, can someone show an example of it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Do you want/need to pass along some session information? Well, you can always just point the url of the new window to a GWT app... How about a `PopupPanel` (plus maybe the `Frame` Widget)?

Comment: I want to create a "Printer Friendly" version of a page, and it would be nice to have it in a separate window. I know it can be done in other ways, I was just wondering if this was even possible.

Comment: I have the same question as Igor. Try avoiding opening new window (except if it's to redirect to another website), since it's really annoying for the user. I'd also suggest the PopupPanel

Comment: In your case, I agree it wouldn't be a bad idea...

Comment: Right, well. I'll try popup panel, the Printable version wouldn't really do much besides display a stripped down version of a results page optimized for printing. It still has dynamic content though, so that's why I was asking. I'm afraid that the popup panel might be confusing to the user as they might see the page under it, not knowing what will get printed.

Comment: Well, if you want to have a preview of a printable version of your website, then yes, a new window (or tab, since most browsers nowadays just open a new tab in such circumstances) is the way to go (unless you can, for example, generate a pdf or any other downloadable format for that printable version). The most elegant way in such case would be to use `History` (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) to fullest - that is open the new window with, say, `&print=true` appended to the url, so that the application can get into a printer-friendly "mode".

Comment: @Igor and everyone: I don't know, but wouldn't it be possible to 1) open a child window and keep the reference to it, 2) create a bit of DOM in the main window, 3) send that to the child window? I have never tried this, could that work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea. I implemented it in pure JavaScript, but if it's possible in JS, it should also be possible with GWT!

parent.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Parent page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openChild() {
            window.mychild = window.open("print.html");
            setTimeout('setContent();', 2000);
    }
    function setContent() {
            window.mychild.document.body.innerHTML = 
               '<b>Here is your dynamically generated print content</b>';
               // This could be produced by your main GWT module.
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:openChild()">Open child window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

print.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Print view</title>
</head>
<body>
    One moment please...
</body>
</html>
```

Note, that I used a timeout. This isn't ideal, because if the (very small) print.html takes longer to be fetched, then it will overwrite the dynamically set content.

I assume, the solution could be optimized (but make sure that the child window is fetched from the same origin, otherwise you'll run into "Same Origin Policy" problems).

Comment: That's actually a great idea, Chris :) It should do the job nicely as long as you expect to put only static content/HTML into that window - any event handlers, etc. won't get transferred (obviously). And I just wanted to add, that one can access the innerHTML value for any Widget via `getElement().getInnerHTML()`. So to get the whole body tag, one would use `RootPanel.get().getElement().getInnerHTML()`.

Comment: Too bad that the GWT version of [Window.open](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#open) doesn't return anything!